# Will PowerPoint Add-In for downloaded PowerPoint work the same for PowerPoint Online?

Tags: visual-studio, ms-office, powerpoint, office-addins, office-js

I'm trying to develop an add-on for PowerPoint Online, but it seems like the easiest way to test the app is by having a downloaded PowerPoint version and testing it there (if this is not the case, please let me know). So do add-ins look and function the same in downloaded PowerPoint and PowerPoint Online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way to test your add-in in Office Online (in this case, in PowerPoint Online is by using an add-in "catalog", either in Office 365 or SharePoint. Here are [instructions for Office Online debugging](http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-in-office-online).

And, as Igaud points out, one of the reasons to test is that not all APIs exist in both places. Another reason is that Chrome/Firefox/Safari could render your page slightly differently, so it's important to make sure the UI is still correct.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, yes, however, not all APIs will exist in both.